# Вызов функции с аргументами в javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

Изучаю javascript. Есть такой код:

```
function sum(a,b) {
    a = +prompt('Input your first number ', a);
    b = +prompt('Input your second number ', b);

    var c = a + b;

    alert( c );
}

sum();
```

Почему если писать `sum(a,b)` браузер ничего не выводит, а если без аргументов `sum()` то все работает ? Спасибо.

Comment: Я не понял вопрос

Comment: когда я возвращаю sum(), то все работает как надо, а если в возвращаю с аргументами sum(a,b), то браузер ничего не выводит. Почему так происходит?

Comment: у меня все работает

Comment: я надеюсь ты не пишешь просто sum(a,b) с не инициализированными переменными!?

Comment: У меня тоже все работает согласен с @VitaliyScherban на счет переменных

Comment: все равно не работает. пишу с инициализированными переменными, но снова пустая страница

Comment: @VitaliyScherban, с такой записью тоже не работает function sum(a,b) {
    var a = +prompt('Input your first number ', a);
    var b = +prompt('Input your second number ', b);

    var c = a + b;

    alert( c );
}

sum(a,b);

Comment: ти не правильно понял

Comment: работает мой код?

Answer (score 1):

```
function sum(a,b) {
a = +prompt('Input your first number ', a);
b = +prompt('Input your second number ', b);

var c = a + b;

alert( c );
}
var a = 1; var b=2;
sum(a,b);`
```

Переменные объявленные в функции не работает вне ее.

Comment: переменные a и b ты уже объявил в самой функции

Comment: понял, спасибо за инфу